# Java Error message. unexpected type, required variable, found value

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement

I am doing a debugging exercise for one of my courses. I have found and fixed all but one error in the code. I have to fix this one error:

```
int input, x; 
if ((input % 2)= 0)  // <- this is the line with the error
    ++input;
else
    --input;
```

I am getting an error on the `input % 2`, it is saying it is looking for a variable not a value

Comment: `=` should be `==`.

Comment: `if ((input % 2) == 0)`

Comment: `if ((input & 1) == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

That is because the assignment operator(=) needs a variable to be assigned to the left side of it. If requires a comparison operator to get a Boolean result. You should use == for the same. After you resolve this issue, you would face another issue because you are trying to use a local variable (index) without initialisation.

Answer (score -1):

You should use == not = for comparing/checking a value
if ((input % 2) == 0)

Comment: at least explain why!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the equal statement "=". This "=" should be replaced with "==". Here are explained details https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

```
int input, x; 
if ((input % 2) == 0)
 ++input;
 else
 --input;
```

Comment: Using the terminology of the tutorial you linked to, `==` is not a _statement_ (which has in Java another [meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)) but the _equality operator_, `=` is the _assignment operator_ ... for the sake of completeness - (didn't down vote)